# AngularJS: How to add two different classes in some condition?

Tags: css, angularjs, class

I have an application built with AngularJs.

Html file contain information like that:

```
<div>
<h3 ng-if="..."></h3>
<h3 ng-if="..."></h3>
<h3 ng-if="..."></h3>
<h3 ng-if="..."></h3>
</div>
```

So on website I can have 4 different elements. If I have just two of then I want to use different classes then with 4 of them.

```
   if(myVar == 0){
        $scope.life_class='';
    }else if(myVar ==1){
        $scope.life_class='doscol';
    }else if(myVar ==2){
        $scope.life_class='tricol';
    }else if(myVar ==3){
        $scope.life_class='foucol';
    }else{
        $scope.life_class='fifcol';
    }
```

And with 'foucol' and 'fifcol' classes I want to add another class, but only in case that 'foucol' and 'fifcol' are in use.

I tried many times with different solutions like that:

```
if(active_date_count >= 2) {
    document.getElementById("h3").foucol += " font_class";
     document.getElementById("h3").tricol += " font_class";
 }
```

But it does't work properly. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you can use `ng-class` to achieve conditional classes.

`<h3 ng-class="{'font_class': condition}" ...></h3>`

For more info, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass